How far past does ODSP (Ontario Disability Support Program) limit non-allowable assets?
How many past years do ODSP's unallowed prescribed asset limits cover? How much past time in records will ODSP judge for these prescribed asset limits?
If I owned $40,000 of non-allowable assets T years ago, but own just $35k today, how will ODSP judge me where T = 1, 2, 3, ...? What T is  the cutoff?

The prescribed asset limits for a benefit unit are $40,000 for a single recipient, $50,000 for a couple and $500 for each dependant other than a spouse.
With the Director's approval, the allowable asset level for a benefit unit may be increased to permit the purchase of an item that is necessary for the health of a member of the benefit unit or for disability related items or services.
A number of assets are exempt including but not limited to a person's interest in a principal residence, one motor vehicle, a prepaid funeral, the cash surrender value of life insurance policies, all funds held in a Registered Disability Savings Plan, tools of the trade, student loans, and a loan used for the purchase of an exempt asset, a principal residence or an asset necessary for the health or welfare of a member of the benefit unit.


I expect there's a big difference between "i used to own a boat, but now that I'm disabled I can't use it so I sold it and used the money to live off" and "I used to own a boat but I nudge-nudge-wink-wink 'sold' it to my brother for a dollar to get my assets under the limit". Why do you feel there's a formula that applies here?
